# Docker build current git branch in gitlab CI

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I have noticed that when `docker run` is executed in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the docker image is built using files from the master branch of the repository, independently on whether a commit is pushed from master or from another branch.

In my current script, I am building an image and running some test similarly as follows:

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKERHUB_IMAGE: "${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/myproject"

services:
    - docker:dind

before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE -p $PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

stages:
    - build
    - test

build_myproject:
    stage: build
    script:
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

test_myproject:
    stage: test
    script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE myproject
    - docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp myproject options input ...
    ...
```

How can I specify there the current branch for building the image?

So far I have tried to install `git` with and use `git checkout` before building with:

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install git
....

script:
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
```

But this does not work with the `docker:stable` image I guess:

> /bin/sh: eval: line 93: apt-get: not found

Following `docker build` documentation ([here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)), I have also tried to build the image from the URL. But I am not sure how to use this. When I run `docker build` with the following code:

```
- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE https://gitlab.com/user/myproject.git#$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

I get again an error that has to do with git.

> unable to prepare context: unable to find 'git': exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH

This makes me wonder if I should ask about how to install `git` within a `docker:stable` image, but I do not want to convert this into a XY problem. Perhaps there is a simpler way to perform this task.

**EDIT**

The error was a mistake on my side, but I will leave the question here in case it helps somebody.

The problem was that in the Dockerfile I was using `git clone` for getting a copy of the repository, instead of directly using the Docker `COPY` command. Of course that way the branch used for docker build was the master one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly unprobable that pipeline triggered from push to custom branch contains files from master branch.
Check logs from executed pipeline for checkout line, e.g. `Checking out <commit sha> as <branch name>...`

To ensure you build new image I would try building with `–no-cache` option.

I can't see `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` declaration in your pipeline definition. Does docker name change or is it constant?
If it doesn't change and you don't mind additional stored images in your repository then you could tag each build with branch specific name. Or even commit specific. Then you would be sure you test proper image.

Comment: `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` is a predefined variable in Gitlab (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)). The original pipeline posted works as expected, but only if changes are consistent with the master branch. It only fails e.g. when configuration files are changed (eg. with different name for an option). So that it works when local testing in the issue branch, but fails when pushed an run in CI, because the docker image built is based on master.

Comment: Did you try building with `--no-cache`?

Comment: Yes I did, but it does't fix it.

Comment: What do pipeline logs say about checkout part? I can't see how it is possible that you push to some non-master branch and git checkout results in mster branch checkout. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The log says `Checking out 8ec6c56e as develop...`. This helped me realized that the problem was elsewhere, and in fact it happened that in the Dockerfile I was cloning the repo (the master branch), instead of copying the source code into the image. I will edit the question for clarity. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Glad I helped:)